# Can I add a native GoogleMap to my Cordova hybrid app?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-maps-api-2, hybrid-mobile-app

Can I add a native google map to one of the pages in my cordova hybrid app?

If yes, please indicate how(in Android and iOS), thanks!

Comment: yes, you can, just search the google maps plugin

Comment: Is it a must to `cordova build` it and then manually add the native google map code by opening the native application project?

Comment: no, you just should install the plugin with the cordova CLI and everything should work (if the plugin you find is updated to support cordova 3.X.X).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can work with googlemaps api for cordova , here is a simple implmentation .
Before that you need to generate your api key from google .
Please find the information in this link
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Here is a simple example for loading a map with your api key .
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

make your index.html look something like this , after u have added the whitelist in the meta tag inside the head section

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<style>
    body, html, #map {  margin: 0;width:100%;height:400px }
#map {
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height: :50%;
}

#map:after {
    width: 22px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -11px;
    background-size: 22px 40px; 
   pointer-events: none; 
}

    </style>



   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        }



    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the googlmap native plugin :

https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps